# Unsupported parse mode

Tags: python, markdown, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to send a message in bold and an error pops up "ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: unsupported parse_mode"

```
import telebot
import markdown

bot = telebot.TeleBot("<MY-BOT-TOKEN>", parse_mode=markdown)



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "hello")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def send(message):
    if message.text == 'hey':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '*bblablalbla*', parse_mode=markdown)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: You've placed your **private BOT token** in the question. I removed it, but it's still visible in the history. Consider renewing the token at @botFather to prevent other people abusing it!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the `parse_mode` as a non-existing variable.

Reading the [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.parsemode.html), you should pass it as a constant, or as a string;

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'test', parse_mode=telegram.constants.PARSEMODE_MARKDOWN)
```

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'test', parse_mode='Markdown')
```